# How can get total number of unread messages off all chats?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a badge that shows in BottomNavigationBar the total number of unread messages
but I have a stream that shows the number of unread messages in every chat. How can I get the sum of this numbers?
Here is my stream:

```
  @override
  Stream<int> getNumMessageNotseen(ChatEntity chat) {
    return firebaseFirestore
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(chat.cid)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('createAt')
        .snapshots()
        .map((messages) {
      int num = 0;
      int index = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < chat.participantsid!.length; i++) {
        if (chat.participantsid![i] == chat.uid) {
          index = i;
        }
      }

      for (var doc in messages.docs) {
        MessageModel message = MessageModel.fromSnapshot(doc);
        if (message.senderid != chat.uid) {
          if (message.isSeen![index] == false) {
            num++;
          }
        }
      }
      return num;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combine` from `rxdart` library.

```
Stream<int> getTotalNumMessageNotseen(List<ChatEntity> chats) {
  List<Stream<int>> streams = chats.map((chat) => getNumMessageNotseen(chat)).toList();
  return CombineLatestStream.list<int>(streams).map((list) => list.fold<int>(0, (sum, num) => sum + num));
}
```